# The difference between a 'view' and 'base' relation

Tags: database, rdbms

What is the difference between a 'view' and 'base' relation in database systems?

Answer (score 15):

A base relation (table) actually contains data.  A view is a query over one (or more) base relations but does not actually contain any data itself.

Comment: speaking of relational database.. views are also called "derived relations"

Answer (score 4):

A base relation is just a table that actually physically exists and is stored in the database.

This is in contrast to a view, which is derived from base relations but does not actually physically exist in the database - it only exists as a structural definition, pulling its data from a number of base relations.

Answer (score 0):

A base relation is a table with some values while a view is essentially some subset of the database that allows each user to have his or her own view of the database